# WooCommerce shipping Calculator query

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set default country USA in the WooCommerce shipping calculator. Can anyone please advise me on how can I set the default country USA in only WooCommerce shipping calculator, not in the checkout field.

```
jQuery('#calc_shipping_country option[value=US]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update the question with some code

Comment: I have tried with jquery. Here is the code jQuery('#calc_shipping_country option[value=US]').attr('selected','selected');

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $country_input = $(this).find('#calc_shipping_country');
    $country_input.val('IN');

});
```

Try this code

Comment: US country now selected by default but the US state did not populate by default.

Comment: You can set state as well the same way.